# Will logging out and in frequently slow my pet kitten's growth?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I'd like to grow my Old School RuneScape pet kitten into a cat.

Will my kitten grow up while I'm doing some activity which requires switching worlds roughly every 30 seconds, or will the frequent logouts/logins slow the kitten's growth?

Comment: It should still grow up, but with prayer flicking and health flicking, you never know...

Answer (score 2):

Your kitten will grow into an adult cat after 180 minutes of the cat following you. You must be online for time to accumulate. So technically, yes, hopping worlds could affect the length of time it takes your kitten to grow, but not by a noticeable amount.